# Making random phone number xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: python, python-2.7

It will return a random phone number xxx-xxx-xxxx with the following restrictions:

- The area code cannot start with a zero,
- None of the middle three digits can be a 9,
- Middle three digits cannot be 000,
- Last 4 digits cannot all be the same.

Comment: Should the last bit - `c` have 4 digits?

Comment: You need to learn how to use `while` loops. Specifically, you want a loop around each random number generator that only exits when the random number matches your criteria.

Comment: One thing you may want to know, your requirements allow for invalid phone numbers to be generated for north ameriacan phone numbers. The offical standard is called [NANP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan)

Comment: @Tunechi Deleting content, making what remains useless, will not do. Press the delete link to delete the entire question if you want to cover up your actions so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly simpler solution.

```
import random

def phn():
    n = '0000000000'
    while '9' in n[3:6] or n[3:6]=='000' or n[6]==n[7]==n[8]==n[9]:
        n = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10-1))
    return n[:3] + '-' + n[3:6] + '-' + n[6:]
```

And a solution that returns the first time, every time (no while loops).

```
import random

def phn():
    p=list('0000000000')
    p[0] = str(random.randint(1,9))
    for i in [1,2,6,7,8]:
        p[i] = str(random.randint(0,9))
    for i in [3,4]:
        p[i] = str(random.randint(0,8))
    if p[3]==p[4]==0:
        p[5]=str(random.randint(1,8))
    else:
        p[5]=str(random.randint(0,8))
    n = range(10)
    if p[6]==p[7]==p[8]:
        n = (i for i in n if i!=p[6])
    p[9] = str(random.choice(n))
    p = ''.join(p)
    return p[:3] + '-' + p[3:6] + '-' + p[6:]
```

Comment: Has a downside of undefined time (in accordance with [Murphy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law), it's gonna choke sometime).

Comment: The probability of randomly choosing a bad phone number in this case is only around 0.1% (9990010 bad numbers out of 9 billion possible numbers) but it is definitely important to keep in mind.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to combine OP,@kgull,@Cyber's code and @ivan_pozdeev's concern, also fulfill OP's requirement :

```
>>> def gen_phone():
    first = str(random.randint(100,999))
    second = str(random.randint(1,888)).zfill(3)

    last = (str(random.randint(1,9998)).zfill(4))
    while last in ['1111','2222','3333','4444','5555','6666','7777','8888']:
        last = (str(random.randint(1,9998)).zfill(4))
        
    return '{}-{}-{}'.format(first,second, last)

>>> for _ in xrange(10):
    gen_phone()
    
'496-251-8419'
'102-665-1932'
'262-624-5025'
'230-459-3242'
'355-131-0243'
'488-001-6828'
'244-539-2369'
'896-547-4539'
'522-406-8256'
'789-373-4240'
```

Comment: for french 10 digits phone number : `def randowPhoneNumber(prefix_digit):
    return '0' + prefix_digit + str(random.randint(100000000, 999999999))` and define _prefix_digit_ to 6 or 7 to mobile phone numbers… You can also replace initial '0' by '33+' to define international number

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
```

Let's start with the area code. No leading zero, so only pick between 1 and 9. Then the remaining two can be anything between 00 and 99.

```
def makeFirst():
    first_digit = random.randint(1,9)
    remaining = random.randint(0,99)
    return first_digit*100 + remaining
```

Next the middle numbers. They cannot have a 9 so sample 0 to 8. Then loop until you get a valid case, throwing out if you happen to sample a 000.

```
def makeSecond():
    middle = 0
    while middle == 0:
        middle1 = random.randint(0,8)
        middle2 = random.randint(0,8)
        middle3 = random.randint(0,8)
        middle = 100*middle1 + 10*middle2 + middle3
    return middle
```

For the last four numbers, we'll use `random.sample` to ensure that we don't get any repeats.

```
def makeLast():
    return ''.join(map(str, random.sample(range(10),4)))
```

Finally join the whole thing together and format it like a phone number.

```
def makePhone():
    first = makeFirst()
    second = makeSecond()
    last = makeLast()
    return '{3}-{3}-{4}'.format(first,second,last)
```

A few tests

```
for i in range(5):
    print makePhone()

425-426-8902
473-775-2793
434-624-8356
287-630-4560
861-431-7659
```

Comment: The similarity in the answer I was about to post and the one you posted is scary.

Comment: `makeLast` will never return a number with 2 or 3 of the numbers the same either. So something like 425-426-8999 isn't possible.

Comment: `random.sample` introduces an additional restriction. Is this acceptable?

Comment: The requirement was "Last 4 digits cannot all be the same.", I made that a bit stricter such that "None of the last 4 digits can be the same as each other". We can lax that requirement if you'd like but it was easier to 1-line that way.

Comment: The middle() can't be 000? Isn't it just easier to do ... `second = ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 8)) for _ in range(3)])`?

Comment: @ssm That could still possibly generate 000.

Answer (score 0):

This is my clean and simple answer.

It allows you to generate a random phone number in a random format.

```py
def generate_phone_number():
    formats = [
        "({}{}{}) {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}",
        "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}",
        "({}{}{})-{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}",
    ]

    ten_numbers = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(10)]
    return random.choice(formats).format(*ten_numbers)
```