# Generating fake phone numbers that are valid based on libphonenumber's rules

Tags: faker, libphonenumber

I'd like to use `libphonenumber` to validate phone numbers, but a number of our integration tests are using `Faker` to generate test data, and the numbers that this generates are not always valid based on the full validation rules defined in `libphonenumber`

Is there any way we can use `libphonenumber` to generate a random set of valid phone numbers? I'm aware of `getExampleNumber` but this isn't suitable as it only returns a single number of a given type.

Comment: I was looking for something like this too. I ended up just generating valid phone numbers by generating a valid (real) zip code, then '555' for the 3 digit section, and then a random 4 digit sequence.

Comment: here is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831787/1731460